# PHP traversing a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following multidimensional array:

```
Array 
( 
  [0] => 57950340 
  [1] => SALE-86 
  [2] => COMPLETE 
  [3] => 
  [4] => 333 
  [5] => 819 
  [6] => Array 
         ( 
         [0] => Array 
                ( 
                 [number] => 1 
                 [product] => Array
                              ( 
                               [id] => 90316 
                               [name] => CLASSIC COCKTAIL 
                              ) 
                [quantity] => 1 
                [price_variation] => 1 
                [modifiers] => Array( )
                [notes] => 
                [unit_price] => 16.3636 
                [unit_tax] => 1.63636 
               ) 
        [1] => Array 
               ( 
                [number] => 2 
                [product] => Array 
                             ( 
                              [id] => 90316 
                              [name] => CLASSIC COCKTAIL 
                             ) 
                [quantity] => 1 
                [price_variation] => 1 
                [modifiers] => Array ( ) 
                [notes] => 
                [unit_price] => 16.3636 
                [unit_tax] => 1.63636 
               ) 
         )
)
```

I'm trying to loop through the array so that I can echo the name of the product items (held within the array at key 6 and echo each of these out on a separate line with the unit price and an the initial order ID (key 0 of the initial array).

I've been trying to do this for a few hours but am going round in very confusing circles, can anyone shed any light on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
<?PHP
  $multi_dimensional_array = [...]; // Your array here

  $order_id = $multi_dimensional_array[0];
  $products_array = $multi_dimensional_array[6];
  foreach($products_array as $product) {
    echo $product['product']['name']." costs ".$product['unit_price'];
    echo " - ORDER: ".$order_id;
    echo "<br/>";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use`foreach` and `is_array()` to check if the values is array then foreach to access the inside variables then lastly you can echo it.

```
 foreach($array as $key => $val)
 {
   if(is_array($val){
     foreach($val as $key2 => $val2)
     {
       //print_r($val2); to see the actual data you are accessing
       echo "ID: " . $val2['product']['id']. ' Product Name: ' . $val2['product']['name'] . ' Quantity: ' . $val2['quantity'];
     }
   }
 }
```